# How to avoid frequent sequence of Wireless security stopped - Wireless security started - Wireless security succeeded?

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, security

I have a second hand laptop Lenovo T470 where already Windows 11 is installed on it.

When using it for some time, I can see the WLAN symbol disappear and reappear shortly afterwards.

When executing as admin

```
netsh wlan show wlanreport
```

I can see several entries in the referring report that indicate issues with the WLAN connectivity:

[image: screenshot showing sequences of Wireless security stopped/started/succeeded]

Unfolding one set of these entries shows:

```
11004   2023-08-28T11:22:36 
[‒]Wireless security stopped.

Network Adapter: Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 8260
Interface GUID: {interface-guid-guid-guid-interface}
Local MAC Address: MY:MA:CA:DD:RE:SS
Network SSID: my_wlan_name
BSS Type: Infrastructure
Security Hint: The operation was successful.
```

.

```
11010   2023-08-28T11:22:36 
[‒]Wireless security started.

Network Adapter: Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 8260
Interface GUID: {interface-guid-guid-guid-interface}
Local MAC Address: MY:MA:CA:DD:RE:SS
Network SSID: my_wlan_name
BSS Type: Infrastructure
Authentication: WPA2-Personal
Encryption: AES-CCMP
FIPS Mode: Disabled
802.1x Enabled: No
```

.

```
11005   2023-08-28T11:22:36 
[‒]Wireless security succeeded.

Network Adapter: Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 8260
Interface GUID: {interface-guid-guid-guid-interface}
Local MAC Address: MY:MA:CA:DD:RE:SS
Network SSID: my_wlan_name
BSS Type: Infrastructure
```

**How can I avoid these entries and get the WLAN connetivity stable?**

Comment: If I were you, I'd capture an 802.11 monitor mode packet trace and see what's happening on the air when these log messages show up. Maybe your laptop is behaving correctly, but your AP keeps de-authing you, and it's really an AP problem you need to fix. Or maybe your laptop is roaming between two APs too much (or between bands of the same AP box). Or maybe it's just the AP doing something completely normal like group key rotation when another device leaves the BSS, and the log messages accidentally make it sound scary.

Comment: @Spiff: thanks for your comment. I have tried to find 802.11 events in monitor mode in Wireshark (started as admin). Not a single 802.11 event is visible there. I assume that my network adapter is not able to capture those events (as mentioned by https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/WLAN for Windows). Afterwards I set a fixed channel both for the 2.4 and 5 GHz frequency band in my (single AP) router. From that moment on, no more of these 110xx events have appeared. Could I therefore assume these messages as minor relevant?